QComboBox List Design
I want to customize QComboBox list background. I need a rounded corner box when i hover. i have attached the picture current and what I need.
I am using QtDesigner for python

here is my stylesheet code
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px; 
}

QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 18px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: black;
    border-left-style: solid; 
    border-top-right-radius: 3px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; 
    background-color: white;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/Black/icons/feather/Black/chevron-down.svg);
    width: 15px; 
    height: 10px;
}

QComboBox:focus {
    border: 2px solid blue; 
}



